# How to pass two string in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have two `UILabel` on xib file and I am using plist file to edit its text.

I would like to increase the line spacing of two `UILabels` "title" and "details".

To increases the line spacing, I implemented `NSMutableAttributedString`. However I do not know how I can pass two string in one class.

Any solution for the problem?

```
class PlaySheetCellLeft: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var LBLTitle:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var LBLDetail:UILabel!

    var message:[String:Any]? {
        didSet{
            guard let msg = self.message else { return  }
            let title = msg["title"] as! String
            self.LBLTitle.text = title
            let details = msg["detail"] as! String
            self.LBLDetail.text = details

            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10

            //error code
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, string: details)

            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            LBLTitle.attributedText = attrString

        }
   }
```

Comment: Don't you want to show title and detail in two different label's?

Comment: yes thats how i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple and easy

if you use different labels for title & details both then

```
// For title 
let attrTitleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)
attrTitleString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrTitleString.length))
LBLTitle.attributedText = attrString

// For detail 
let attrDetailsString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: details)
attrDetailsString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrDetailsString.length))
LBLDetail.attributedText = attrDetailsString
```

for single label

```
let labelString = "\(title)\n\(details)"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelString)

// Set common attribute for both title & detail (according to your code)
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

// You can also set differnt attribute for title & details
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(<... set range for title...>))

attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(<...Set range for details....>))

<you label instance - LBLTitle or LBLDetail>.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. With your code and line spacing is increased, but I get two title and two details seen in the device. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to create one NSMutableAttributedString from two different strings. But what you should do is create two separate NSMutableAttributedString instances - one for title and one for detail.